# Making phone calls from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: peripherals, communication

I'm wondering if there is a way I can make phone calls (not over the internet) from a Raspberry Pi product I'm developing (only make them, not receive them).

I thought on the following approaches, however couldn't find much information about them:

- Some kind of paid service, that given a specific peripheral, I can make real phone calls.
- Contact local communication companies to provide custom solutions.

Does anyone has any experience with the cellular networks and the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Assuming you have a standrad text of the call you can use something like twilio. If you want to access celluar service you could look into the fona from adafruit https://learn.adafruit.com/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/overview I linked to the turorial page about connecting it to the Pi but it has a product link and full instructions.

Comment: why not use a VOIP service? Use the Pi to connect to your VOIP provider and they handle all the connection to PSTN (normal telephones) at a reasonable fee.
doing this removes the need for a separate peripheral. try VOIP.MS. They are also starting to support SMS I and many other have experience with Linux/Pi and cellular networks? what are you trying to do?

Comment: This question is overly broad, and isn't specific to the Raspberry Pi.  I would suggest editing your question to be more specific, otherwise it will probably end up being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post I deduct that you are looking for a cellular-based solution, not VoIP ( `(not over the internet)` ) nor land-line based ( `Does anyone has any experience with the`**cellular networks**`and the Raspberry Pi?`). If you did want to consider these you could look at using [web.skype.com](http://web.skype.com) for Skype calls, or setting up PBX software on your rPi (Google for Asterisk PBX).

If you really want to do cellular, things are a bit tricky - but [this stackexchange post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/pi-to-act-as-gsm-voice-phone) might be of help. It is a bit old (2 years), however, it mentions that certain Huawei dongles might be able to do what you are looking for. The component it uses (chan_dongle) is located [here](http://wiki.e1550.mobi/doku.php?id=Main%20page), but is also 2 years old - so you would have to do some experimenting to check if it still works. Alternatively, as user ppumkin mentions in his accepted answer, you can run Asterisk PBX on the Pi and use a hardware GSM gateway to handle the cellular traffic for you. From what I can see those gateways are pretty expensive though (>$200).